# GoogleTV (3.1) - streaming audio supported in MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, shoutcast, google-tv, icecast

I'm migrating some existing Android code to GoogleTV, and I cannot get any HTTP audio streams (Icecast/Shoutcast) to play in a MediaPlayer object. Setting an Icecast URI as the data source for the MediaPlayer works on every device I've ever tested (including Android 3.1 tablets), but it does not work on my 3.1 Fishtank device.

Here is part of the logcat output:

```
    11-16 21:46:01.798: I/AVAPIMediaPlayer(142): Found HTTP success.  Connection is HTTP/1.0, code was 200
    11-16 21:46:01.798: I/AVAPIMediaPlayer(142): Found content type audio/mpeg
    11-16 21:46:01.802: W/AVAPIMediaPlayer(142): Error, reached end of headers before finding required fields.
    11-16 21:46:01.802: E/AVAPIMediaPlayer(142): Source encountered an error while asynchronously preparing.
    11-16 21:46:01.802: E/MediaPlayer(30735): error (0, 0)
    11-16 21:46:01.802: E/MediaPlayer(30735): start called in state 0
    11-16 21:46:01.802: E/MediaPlayer(30735): error (-38, 0)
    11-16 21:46:01.806: E/MediaPlayer(30735): Error (-38,0)
```

I hope this is just a problem with the dev device. There are a lot of existing apps which depend on MP3 streaming. Is it specifically not supported in GoogleTV?

Comment: Could you send us some URIs to test this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your response until just now. This is the test stream we usually use http://vprbbc.streamguys.net/vprbbc24.mp3 or http://u17.di.fm:80/di_goapsy -- I can't post our production URL here because it is public. I have also tested on a Revue and I get similar results.

Comment: This was added to the official GTV issue tracker here [link](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google TV 2.0 doesn't support SHOUTcast protocol. Hopefully this feature will be added on future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the exact same thing and when I could not get it working I utilized this opensource project to eventually get everything working smoothly.

```
https://github.com/Dawnthorn/nagare/
```

Comment: This is a good project to inspect for ideas, but it saves the entire stream to /sdcard which is not desirable in most cases. (It does work on Google TV, however.)

Comment: I didn't use the project in its entirety, only what was necessary for my implementation.

Comment: Was there any actual solution to this?

handlerexploit is there a snippet you can show what part of the project you used?